# Reused UIWebView showing previous loaded content for a brief second on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

In one of my apps I reuse a webview. Each time the user enters a certain view on reload cached data to the webview using the method :-

> `- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL`

and I wait for the callback call

> `- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.`

In the mean time I hide the webview and show a 'loading' label.
Only when I receive webViewDidFinishLoad do I show the webview.

Many times what happens I see the previous data that was loaded to the webview for a brief second before the new data I loaded kicks in.

I already added a delay of 0.2 seconds before showing the webview but it didn't help.

Instead of solving this by adding more time to the delay does anyone know how to solve this issue or maybe clear old data from a webview without release and allocating it every time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks malaki1974, in my case I wasn't using a modal view.
When I sat with an Apple engineer on WWDC 2010 and asked him this question his answer was simply: "Don't reuse UIWebViews, that's not how they were ment to be used."
Since then I make sure to calls this set of lines before allocating a new UIWebView

```
[self.myWebView removeFromSuperview];
self.myWebView.delegate = nil;
[self.myWebView stopLoading];
[self.myWebView release];
```

That solved the issue.

Comment: Really? That's a really dumb thing of Apple to do considering Webviews are expensive to create

Comment: That's why I wanted to reuse them in the first place. But the Apple engineer strongly insisted they weren't meant to be reused (at least at that point in life when iOS4 was just introduced). I must admit that since I implemented his advice I didn't encounter the problem any more.

Comment: Well.. I can't live without reusing considering how expensive it is. It works nicely for me using the @"about:blank"-trick...

Comment: anyone know the solution for ARC since we can't release?

Answer (score 7):

Clear the contents of the webview before you try to load new content

```
[self loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation on this one? This shows an empty webview... but how does it connect to the content-delay problem?

Comment: Ah, I get it. It's not about the delay, but about clearing the content before showing the new!

Comment: Yep. That's the idea. I'm posting another alternative now too.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `UIWebView` renders it contents in a background thread. Even when you receive `webViewDidFinishLoad:` it might not be completely done. Specially if it is an ajax-intense page that comes from the network.

You say you are hiding the view. I wonder if that means that the webview delays its drawing completely. What you could try is to move the `UIWebView` offscreen or obscure it with another view. Maybe that will change it's drawing behaviour.

If you do not need an interactive `UIWebView` then you can also consider to do it completely offscreen in a separate `UIWindow` and then create an image from that `UIWebView`'s layer.

Comment: "it might not be completely done" - Is there a way to know when it's completely done?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I do, and it works:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close();"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading a local file that is blank or has a loading graphic when you hide it, rather than just loading new content when you show it.  Since the file is local it will be quick and even if the new page takes a while to load it will have either blank or loading expected behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helpful. Even loadHTMLString:@"<html><body></body></html>" has enough time lag to be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you got controll over the html. You can communicate back to objective-c when the document is ready. Like so in jQuery:

```
function messageNative (name, string) {

    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");

    iframe.setAttribute("src", "appscheme://" + name + "/" + string);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
} 

$(function() {  
    messageNative('webview', 'ready');
});
```

And then in UIWebView's delegate method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: wait for the request with url equal to "appscheme://webview/ready". Then you should know: the document is loaded and ready for display. Then all that is missing is a simple fade-in or something like that :)