# webViewDidFinishLoad did finish loading but didn't finish showing content on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiwebview

I'm using `webViewDidFinishLoad` a lot in my app and there's something about `UIWebView` that really bugs me, well, actually two things.
The first, when I load new content to a `UIWebView` I will see for half a second the last page that was loaded to the same `UIWebView` what will force me to "clean" the `UIWebView` using something like:

```
[_mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close();"];
```

before loading the new content.

The second issue I have and that's the main issue for this question is that if i'll load some new content to my `UIWebView` and do something like this:

```
[_mainWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
...
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
            _mainWebView.alpha = 1;
    }
```

In some cases the `UIWebView` will show up white for half a second before showing up the content. I'm guessing that the content is already loaded into the `UIWebView` and that's why `webViewDidFinishLoad:webView` is firing but for small html pages showing to content takes loner than the actual load. Is there any workaround I can use to avoid the blank screen that is showing for a sec or so but still save that second?

I thought about animating the alpha from 0 to 1 but that solution feels kinda lame to me.

Comment: Do you have control over the html? Or you're willing to download and manipulate the html? If so, you could add some javascript to the page that runs a callback in your app...

Comment: I download the htmls before displaying it. Sounds interesting, I'm willing to try. :)

Comment: The code shown isn't really much to go on. Please can you provide some more to show exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I adde done line of code to make it more understood but the only thing I'm doing is loading an html into a webview and showing the webview when it's loaded. The problem is that the webview is shown before the content is loaded because of the `UIWebView` background thread as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311564/reused-uiwebview-showing-previous-loaded-content-for-a-brief-second-on-iphone/2311935#2311935

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a javascript callback so you know when the web view contents have actually loaded: [Javascript in UIWebView callback to C/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c)